# How to get Auto-renewable in-app purchase status?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, auto-renewing

I am implementing auto-renewable in app-purchase. Here user can access application on difrent devices either iOS or android. when user is in app and allow purchase a auto-renewable subscription Then

1). is he will get a transaction success method or something same?

if yes
Then i submit a success bool and subscription end-time on local-server by hit a api-url. but my problem is

2). how can i get to know that money has been deducted from itunes (in automatically renew process)?

3).how can i get subscriptions state to save it on local server, if user never use that app on that device, or he changed his device from iOS to android?

Comment: You can access the current subscription state through the receipt that is available to your app. This is covered in the Apple in-app purchase guide. While you could store the subscription state in your server and use that in an Android app but you can't get renewal status without the user running the iOS app.

Comment: @Paulw11 how can i get to know that my money has been deducted if last i used app on march 29th, money deduct on march 30th and i relaunch app on april  1st.

Comment: Your app simply finds out about the expiration date (or the new expiration date once the subscription renews) by examining the receipt when it launches. The amount of money is set through iTunesConnect.